# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not returning the updated object despite {new: true} option when using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have read almost every answer on SO regarding this, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. I think it has more to do with my inchoate understanding of promises.

My express application is structured using MVC & services design pattern.
I have a following service method, which concerns me:

```js
const incrementPoolSize = async (params, ...rest) => {
    const { network } = params;

    if (network.currPoolSize >= network.maxPoolSize) {
        console.error('Max Pool Size reached');
    } else {
        try {
            // console.log(await Network.find({}).exec());
            const x = await Network.findOneAndUpdate(
                {  _id: network._id },
                { $inc: { currPoolSize: 1 }},
                {  new: true }
            ).exec();
            console.log(x);
            return x;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
};
```

The callback version which works:

```js
const incrementPoolSize = async (params, ...rest) => {
    const { network } = params;

    if (network.currPoolSize >= network.maxPoolSize) {
        console.error('Max Pool Size reached');
    } else {
        try {
            console.log(await Network.find({}).exec());
            const x = await Network.findOneAndUpdate(
                {  _id: network._id },
                { $inc: { currPoolSize: 1 }},
                {  new: true },
                (err, doc) => {
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    console.log(doc);
                }
            );
            console.log(x);
            return x;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**: The console.log(x), console.log(doc) differ (tried it for the callback version). I cannot understand this, any explanation would be really helpful. Here are the outputs of console.logs of doc and x respectively:

```
console.log(doc)
doc= {
    maxPoolSize: 10000,
    currPoolSize: 1,
    _id: 5ec916c639275a0df34a99dc,
    createdAt: 2020-05-23T12:27:50.623Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-23T12:27:50.679Z,
    __v: 0
}

console.log(x)
x= {
    maxPoolSize: 10000,
    currPoolSize: 2,
    _id: 5ec916c639275a0df34a99dc,
    createdAt: 2020-05-23T12:27:50.623Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-05-23T12:27:50.679Z,
    __v: 0
}
```

As per mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) & [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), findOneAndUpdate is an atomic function which should return a query, which on execution should return the updated copy of the object, when the option {new: true} is passed. Am I missing something here? However, the console logs `null` for the const x in the above code (and the method incrementPoolSize returns `null`).

My debugging led me to this:

- If I uncomment the `console.log(await Network.find({}).exec());` line before the findOneAndUpdate() call, the console.log(x) logs the updated document with an incremented currPoolSize, exactly as expected. I really don't understand this behaviour.
- If I switch to using a callback style findOneAndUpdate function instead of async/await, then I get the updated document within the callback - as expected (but it too needs the `find({}).exec()` line to be uncommented, see the second code block above).
- Mongoose documentation says, that findOneAndUpdate should return the old object without {new: true} option, but in my case(when `find({}).exec()` is commented) x is null irrespective of the {new: true} option.

Here are some contextual details:

`network` is an object which has been successfully saved into the collection `networks` for the mongoose model `Network` before calling the async method `incrementPoolSize`.

The schema for 'Network' has the following fields, among others:

```
- maxPoolSize
- currPoolSize
...and others
```

My mongoose connection has the following set:

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

Version details:

```
express:  4.16.1
mongodb:  3.5.7
mongoose: 5.9.15
node:     12.16.3
```

Comment: why do you need the `exec()` there? I think it should work without it.

Comment: have you tried .findByIdAndUpdate() instead ?

Comment: @virtual_Black_Whale yes I tried it as well, it exhibits the same behaviour. Been debugging long now, replaced it with more generic findOneAndUpdate in the process.

Comment: @PabloCG The documentation says that findOneAndUpdate returns a query unless a callback parameter is specified. Hence to execute the query I called exec.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the `findOneAndUpdate` method with callback that's giving you the correct response

Comment: @Vishnu, updated with callback version as requested